# How to convert a hex-string into an unpacked IEEE 754 format number:-

Tags: python, ieee-754

using Python 2.7.3: How to convert a hex-string into an unpacked IEEE 754 format number:-

I have a string of hex data in this form:

```
data = '38 1A A3 44'
```

I would like to convert this to a floating point number by using struct.unpack:

```
fdata = struct.unpack('<f','\x38\xA1\xA3\x44')  # fdata=1304.8193359375
```

Is there a Pythonic solution or do I need to somehow substitute an escape sequence for each space in *data*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the hex codepoints to a byte string first; [`binascii.unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) can do this for you, provided you remove the whitespace:

```
import binascii
import struct

fdata = struct.unpack('<f', binascii.unhexlify(data.replace(' ', '')))[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> data = '38 1A A3 44'
>>> struct.unpack('<f', binascii.unhexlify(data.replace(' ', '')))
(1304.8193359375,)
```

Comment: I came up with an alternate way to convert from hex: `''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in data.split())`. Yours is better.